# Using pcap to parse through a trace file?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, pcap, packets

I'm currently learning about TCP and packets. I'm working in the C programming language, and I understand how the `pcap` library can be used to sniff traffic on my computer. But can `pcap` be used to parse and read through a trace file as well? I need to track the TCP state information from a given trace file.

In a nutshell, I'm curious how I can go about opening a trace file with `pcap` to parse through it? If someone could get me moving towards the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But can pcap be used to parse and read through a trace file as well?

Yes.  Most of the APIs you'd use are the same, but you'd use `pcap_open_offline()` to open a file rather than using `pcap_open_live()`, or `pcap_create()` and `pcap_activate()`, to open a device for a live capture.